# Netbeans 7.1 FTP QUIT command

Tags: netbeans, ftp, netbeans-7

My FTP server reset connection every 120 seconds. It's involve error:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,98,2,230,204,124).
STOR style.css.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for style.css.new
226 Transfer complete
RNFR style.css.new
350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name
RNTO style.css
250 Rename successful
CWD /site/templates/css
421 Idle timeout (120 seconds): closing control connection
```

if I upload file after 120 seconds.

In the Netbeans 7.0.1 on every uploaded file I get this in console:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,98,2,230,214,189). 
STOR style.css.new 
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for style.css.new 
226 Transfer complete 
RNFR style.css.new 
350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name 
RNTO style.css 
250 Rename successful 
QUIT 
221 Goodbye.
```

and I haven't any errors after 120 seconds.

I think problem in last two strings... Netbeans 7.1 doesn't run

```
QUIT 
221 Goodbye.
```

after file uploaded.

How can I enable QUIT command in FTP of Netbeans 7.1? Thank you.

Comment: Excellent question. I've been having the same exact problem and it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct solution to the problem, but it's a workaround. In your PHP project properties, go to the category **Run Configuration**. Save your current config, "<default>", and then create a new config, which you set to run as **Local Web Site (running on local web server)**. I called mine "offline" but you can name it whatever you want. After you're done making changes to your project online, if you set the configuration from "<default>" to "offline", NetBeans will execute the FTP command `QUIT`. Just don't forget to go back online when you need to.

There are a number of ways to set the configuration. You could go to the **Project Properties** dialog window and set it in the **Run Configuration** Category; you could right click on your project in the **Projects** window and then go to the **Set Configuration** sub-menu; or you can use the config drop-down list in your toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I edit and save files often and this solution don't fits for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties. Then go to "Run Configuration". There you can then click on the Manage button for your Remote Connection. At the bottom of the input fields you will find one for the "Keep-alive interval(s)". By default it is set to 30 seconds. If you enter a 0 instead, it disables the keep-alive feature. When I did it, it didn't send a quit right away, but it did after about 10 seconds or so.